# Data processing inequality for renyi divergence

Tags: information-theory

Anyone know a reference that demonstrates that classical Renyi divergence satisfies a data processing inequality (DPI)? Here by data-processing I mean 'application of an arbitrary bistochastic map on both arguments of the divergence' -- and I want this to decrease the value of the divergence. The statement on the first page of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1001.4448.pdf does not satisfy my definition as it only considers projection onto a subalgebra.

Comment: The Renyi divergence is a one-one monotone map of a $f$-divergence (in particular, $D_\alpha(P\|Q) = (\alpha-1)^{-1} \log ( 1 + (\alpha-1)\mathcal{H}_\alpha(P\|Q) ),$ where $\mathcal{H}_\alpha$ is the $\alpha$-Hellinger divergence). As a consequence it inherits a data processing inequality from the general DPI for $f$-divergences (see [here](http://www.stat.yale.edu/~yw562/teaching/598/lec04.pdf) for instance).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: The Answer is YES! You can check Theorem 9 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.2459.pdf.